# Azure MFA and Bearer Tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, multi-factor-authentication

So the crux of my problem is that I am having difficulty finding the relation to a successful SSO/MFA authentication and the issued bearer token.

I've created a SPA application which uses an issued bearer token for authentication and authorization, and For the purposes of the application I manually invalidate the bearer token after 10 minutes to bypass the limit set in place by azure of 1 hour. My ideal situation is that every time a user has their session invalidated from the application that they will have to reauthenticate with their SSO and MFA.

I am trying to understand if/how the MFA is tied to the bearer token and when I invalidate the token whether the user will have to re-authenticate with MFA once again to sign-in and start using the application again. Presumably it is tied to the user account and the MFA authentication lasts for as long as the conditional access policy dictates.

Comment: I don't think the user would need to go through MFA again if it is only your app that considers the token invalid. How did invalidate the tokens?

Comment: @juunas I force a logout with the msal library and in the back end refuse the requests of a token over a specific amount of time

Comment: Ah, then SSO is lost I think. Since MSAL will request for sign out from AAD.

Comment: @juunas Right so I guess to reiterate my question, will a user have to re-authenticate with MFA because the token is invalidated by AAD

Comment: Now that one I'm not 100% sure about. Would have to test.

Comment: I've been getting mixed reports by users and my own experience, and I'm not an AAD admin in my organization so I can't adjust or test a CA policy unfortunately. thanks for the discussion!